# Going fullscreen in an itunes like application (cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, 3d, nsview

I have a cocoa application that has a finder like feel it and is made up of five views.  On the left there is a gallery which is a finder like interface to choose a given object.  This view stretches across the whole height of the window.  Then on the right I have a window for a 3D simulation view and then below it I have three editing views.  I would like to be able to press a button and have the 3d view take over the entire window and then go into fullscreen mode, and I am wondering if a more experienced Cocoa developer could give me some advice on how I might want to try this.  Should I be removing all the other subviews then resizing the window and 3d view to the size of the screen or would it make more sense to try and just stretch the 3d view to the size of the screen and push the other interface pieces off the screen that way?  I would like to eliminate the menu bar when this occurs to have a real full screen feel for me 3d view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the NSView method `enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:`.  It's easier than you think.